# FuncAnimation produces one more frame than intended at startup

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

Watch closely as the GUI starts up. The first iteration appears to be doubling for some reason. I have the frames parameter set to 4 (equivalent to range(4)), so we should only see four points, but we have 5. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random


def animate(_):
    x = random.uniform(0, 10)
    y = random.uniform(0, 10)

    plt.scatter(x, y, color='maroon', marker='x')


plt.xlim((0, 10))
plt.ylim((0, 10))
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=4, interval=1000, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up [FuncAnimation's manual page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html):

> init_func: callable, optional
>
> A function used to draw a clear frame. **If not given, the results of drawing from the first item in the frames sequence will be used.** This function will be called once before the first frame.

As no explicit `init_func` is given, `animate(0)` is called instead. You can provide a dummy `init_func` to prevent this.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random

def init_func():
    pass

def animate(frame):
    x = random.uniform(0, 10)
    y = random.uniform(0, 10)
    plt.scatter(x, y, color='maroon', marker='x')

plt.xlim((0, 10))
plt.ylim((0, 10))
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, init_func=init_func, frames=4, interval=1000, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is the answer! Very helpful. Thank you!